# Switching the gerunds place changes the meaning?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

I'm always place Gerunds after the things what I want to imply. But, when I occasionally look back at my sentence, it seems odd to me; I can't explain the difference in meaning. My question is: must a Gerund be placed before or after?

> There must be something going wrong.
>    There must be something wrong going

How does each usage change the meaning?

Comment: I wonder if you meant you do this (use gerunds) with any verbs, or just *going*.

Comment: @Damkerng T. With any verbs or a noun another example : there must be an activity existing/ there must be an existing activity

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really have anything to do with the gerund/participle form; it's a matter of two different idioms using the verb *go*:

1. *Go wrong* means to take a (figurative) wrong path: a man or woman who *goes wrong* becomes a criminal, a machine which *goes wrong* malfunctions, a situation which *goes wrong* has unexpected undesirable results. So if you say *There must be something going wrong* you mean something like "There must be some factor in this situation which is screwing things up".

Your second version should read "There must be something wrong going **on**". *Wrong* here is no part of the idiom with *go*—it's an adjective modifying *something*.

2. *Go on* has a variety of meanings: to "go further", to "continue", to "talk nonsense" or "talk too much", to "occur". In the progressive it often means to "be happening", "be in progress": "There's a party *going on* at Joe's apartment", "What's going on, guys?". So if you say *There must be something wrong going on* you are expressing the opinion that "Something is happening which we won't like when we discover what it is."

Answer (score -1):

First, the main point: **going** is being used as an **adjective** modifying the noun **wrong**.

```
There must be something going wrong
```

This is a complete sentence. Full Stop. Without context, I would read it in a concerned, or astonished voice, but that says more about me.

```
There must be something wrong going
```

This is a sentence fragment. There needs to be more verbiage after *going* to fill the reader in on what actually *is going* wrong.

Comment: **going** is an adjective?

Comment: @CK - Indeed: "going rate", "going wrong", "going south", "...any jobs going?" More British than American in usage, but an Adjective nonetheless.

Comment: @CopperKettle Nope.